# How do I join records together and seperate them with "-"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to join records together and separate them with "-"

I know how to join one table records together like this:

```
@keywords = @tweet.hash_tags.join("-")
```

But what if it's HABTM associated tables.

For example.

```
// BRAND MODEL
has_and_belongs_to_many :categories

// CATEGORY MODEL
has_and_belongs_to_many :brands
```

If I do this:

```
@brands = Brand.all  
@brand_categories = @brands.categories.join("-")
```

I get this result:

```
#<Category:0x0000010445c928>,#<Category:0x0000010445c7c0>,#<Category:0x0000010445c5e0>,#<Category:0x0000010445c400>,#<Category:0x0000010445c270>
```

Hope you understand my question - thanks.

Comment: Don't quite understand your question. Could you give an example of the output you're expecting to see?

Comment: What I want to see is: category name 1-category name 2-category name 3-etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#join` will call `#to_s` on the items in the `Array` returned by `@brands.categories` by default, and it doesn't look like you've defined a custom `Category#to_s`. Either do so, or be more explicit about the string representation you want; if, for example, a `Category` has a `title` attribute, you could use:

```
@brands_categories = @brands.categories.map(&:title).join("-")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `Category` table has a `name` field:

```
@brand_categories = @brands.categories.collect(&:name).join("-")
```

This will put all of the `name` values into an array, and then join those.

Comment: Worked great but I can only accept on as an aswer but thanks for helping me out...